# Pointer refresh

Tags: c

I haven't programmed any C for a while and in preparation to take on a side project I decided to write up a few basic functions to get my brain back into thinking in C. One of them I attempted is basic char array copy function:

```
char* mysteryFuncOne(char* in)
{
    char* returnVal = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(in));
    int i = 0;

    while(*(returnVal+ i)= *(in+ i))
    {
        i++;
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

What I have above works, but I'm attempting to further jolt my memory and I also thought this could work:

```
char* mysteryFuncOne(char* in)
{
    char* returnVal = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(in));

    while(*(returnVal++)= *(in++) ) // I changed this loop
    {

    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Basically I changed the conditions of the while loop. I thought these were equivalent forms? The first version works just fine, the second version however returns me an empty result. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here but I just can't spot it.

Anyone want to show me the obvious thing I'm missing?

Comment: what does this `**while(*(returnVal++)= *(in++) )**` mean? Are you used `**` to emphasize it?

Comment: Yes, I meant to make it bold. Removed it now.

Comment: `malloc` will fail when there is not enough heap available, and then it will return null. You should check for it ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second version, you return a pointer to the *end* of the new array.